# Pegar valor unchecked com PHP

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho um formulário que contém o seguintes campos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que selecionei o primeiro e o terceiro campo como encomenda, porém quando cadastro no banco de dados, ele me retorna da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando na verdade tinha que me trazer o ID 2 nulo e o ID 3 como Sim. Para tentar solucionar, fiz dessa forma:

```
$valorEncomenda = ($encomendaP[$i] == null)?("Não"):("Sim");
```

Mas é cadastrado dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja abaixo o código completo:

**Campos do formulário:**

```
<input type="text" name="TamanhoP[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho">
<input type="text" name="EstoqueProd[]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque">
<input type="checkbox" name="EncomendaProd[]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  function removeCampo() {
    $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
    $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
       if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
  }

  $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    //novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
    novoCampo.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('selected', false);
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    removeCampo();
  });
});
</script>
```

**Pego os valores do formulário:**

```
$estoqueP = $_POST["EstoqueProd"];
$tamanhoP = $_POST["TamanhoP"]; 
$encomendaP = $_POST["EncomendaProd"];
$metodos->cadastrar($estoqueP,$tamanhoP,$encomendaP);
```

**Método cadastrar():**

```
public function($idProdutos,$estoqueP,$tamanhoP,$encomendaP){

........

 if($estoqueP[0] != ""){
   for($i = 0; $i <= count($tamanho); $i++){
       if($estoqueP[$i] != ""){
          $valorEncomenda = ($encomendaP[$i] == null)?("Não"):("Sim");
           mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO tabela VALUES(null,'".$idProdutos."','".$tamanho[$i]."','".$estoqueP[$i]."','".$valorEncomenda."');");               
       }
   }
 }

........

}
```

Como posso dar valor ao unchecked?

Comment: Está usando algum javascript?

Comment: Olá rray. Tem sim. Atualizei no post.

Comment: Digo usa algum javascript ou ajax na hora de gravar? a solução mais simples é trocar  o checkbox por um select assim sempre algum valor é enviado. Se usar javascript para enviar os valores para o php ainda dá para o checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma que você estruturou seu HTML não permitirá que você recupere os dados corretamente. Veja que, considerando três produtos, você terá algo como:

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="TamanhoP[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho">
  <input type="text" name="EstoqueProd[]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque">
  <input type="checkbox" name="EncomendaProd[]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="TamanhoP[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho">
  <input type="text" name="EstoqueProd[]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque">
  <input type="checkbox" name="EncomendaProd[]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="TamanhoP[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho">
  <input type="text" name="EstoqueProd[]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque">
  <input type="checkbox" name="EncomendaProd[]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda
</div>
```

Preenchendo tal como na imagem fornecida na pergunta e fazendo `var_dump($_POST)` no servidor que trata a submissão do formulário, teríamos algo como:

```
array(3) {
  ["TamanhoP"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "32"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "33"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "34"
  }
  ["EstoqueProd"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "11"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  ["EncomendaProd"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
  }
}
```

Perceba que o *array* `EncomendaProd` vem apenas com dois valores, referentes ao primeiro e terceiro produto no formulário. Isso já era o esperado, porém, o problema é que não temos como saber quais foram os produtos selecionados. Poderiam ser (1, 2), (1, 3) e (2, 3) que a requisição seria exatamente a mesma. O que você deve fazer é diferenciar cada produto dos outros. Você pode fazer isso indicando o índice de cada produto no nome do campo, definindo o nome do campo propriamente dito como um índice secundário. Por exemplo:

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="produtos[0][tamanho]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho">
  <input type="text" name="produtos[0][estoque]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque">
  <input type="checkbox" name="produtos[0][encomenda]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="produtos[1][tamanho]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho">
  <input type="text" name="produtos[1][estoque]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque">
  <input type="checkbox" name="produtos[1][encomenda]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="produtos[2][tamanho]" class="form-control" placeholder="Tamanho">
  <input type="text" name="produtos[2][estoque]" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Estoque">
  <input type="checkbox" name="produtos[2][encomenda]" value="Sim" style="width: 20px">Encomenda
</div>
```

Perceba que para o produto 1, cada campo é definido como um índice secundário em `produtos[0]`. O mesmo para o segundo produto em `produtos[1]` e para o terceiro produto em `produtos[2]`. Desta forma, ao submeter o formulário, teríamos o seguinte resultado para `var_dump($_POST)`:

```
array(1) {
  ["produtos"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["tamanho"]=>
      string(2) "32"
      ["estoque"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["encomenda"]=>
      string(3) "Sim"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["tamanho"]=>
      string(2) "33"
      ["estoque"]=>
      string(2) "12"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["tamanho"]=>
      string(2) "34"
      ["estoque"]=>
      string(2) "13"
      ["encomenda"]=>
      string(3) "Sim"
    }
  }
}
```

Perceba que para o produto 2 não estará definido o índice `encomenda`, indicando que o mesmo não foi selecionado. Para obter os dados, basta iterar sobre o *array* `$_POST["produtos"]`:

```
foreach ($_POST["produtos"] as $produto) {
    $tamanho = $produto["tamanho"];
    $estoque = $produto["estoque"];
    $encomenda = $produto["encomenda"] ?? "Não";

    echo $tamanho, $estoque, $encomenda, "<br>";
}
```

> Lembrando que o operador de coalescência nula (`??`) só foi inserido no PHP 7. Para versões anteriores será necessário fazer: `$encomenda = isset($produto["encomenda"]) ? $produto["encomenda"] : "Não"`.

A saída seria algo como:

```
32 11 Sim
33 12 Não
34 13 Sim
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado Anderson.